# What version of DisplayPort does the Dell XPS L520X use? Or is there software that can check?

Tags: displayport, dell-xps, mini-displayport

I have this laptop in hand. Is there software that can check? Nvidia GT 540M 2GB

Is it

- 2560×1600 (WQXGA) DisplayPort 1.1a

or

- 4096x2160 (4K) DisplayPort 1.2

Comment: "Is there software that can check?"  **NO;**  There is not.  The simplest way to check, is to connect it to a monitor, and set the resolution to the highest supported resolution. Without specifics on the laptop this answer is basically unanswerable.  The `GeForce 500 Series` does not appear to have any support for DisplayPort based on my research.  It wasn't until the `GeForce GTX 600` was there support for DisplayPort 1.2 so **IF** your GPU even supports it, and that is a big **IF**, it would be DisplayPort 1.1a

Comment: This is a laptop and I can see a display port on it. Also looking up the specs of the laptop it lists display port. So you think it would be 1.1a then?